Why can't Sized traits be made into an object?
This code compiles fine:
trait Trait {}

struct Foo {}
impl Trait for Foo {}

fn do_work(_: &dyn Trait) {}

But if I add Sized as a supertrait...
trait Trait: Sized {}

...it fails:
error[E0038]: the trait `Trait` cannot be made into an object
 --> src\main.rs:6:16
  |
6 | fn do_work(_: &dyn Trait) {}
  |                ^^^^^^^^^ `Trait` cannot be made into an object
  |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
 --> src\main.rs:1:14
  |
1 | trait Trait: Sized {}
  |       -----  ^^^^^ ...because it requires `Self: Sized`

I understand the Sized supertrait prevents object safety, but I don't understand why. I've read the RFC from 2014 that deals with the issue, but I still don't quite comprehend the reason behind it.
Why does the Sized supertrait prevent traits to be used as trait objects?
Note: there are excellent answers below. In case you got confused by the same thing that I was: the Sized supertrait doesn't only mean that each implementor should be Sized. It also means that the trait object itself must be sized.

Most of what I've written here about dyn Sized applies to Trait: Sized as well.

Since your note is part of understanding the problem posed in the question it would be much better in an answer than in the question. If you can't fit it in an existing one, just answer your own question.

"It also means that the trait object itself must be sized." - this is only the case because the trait is implemented for the trait object.  dyn Trait could exist for a Sized trait were that not the case, although you wouldn't be able to do very much with it.

Having a trait object, eg of type &dyn Trait, is only useful if Trait is implemented for the (unsized) type dyn Trait (the compiler provides such implementation for you automatically).
But if Trait is restricted to Sized types, such implementation cannot exist.

Thanks! Turns out, I was confused by something else (see my edit in the original post), but your answer made me realize what I was wrong about.

The Sized trait in Rust indicates that the type implementing the trait has a known size at compile time. This means that by adding Sized as a supertrait to your trait, you're essentially saying that the trait cannot be implemented for types whose size is not known at compile time. Traits with this constraint cannot be used to create trait objects because the size of the object is not known until runtime, which conflicts with the requirement of Sized trait.

TLDR: Because we have two sets of conflicting information. For dyn, type is not known at compile time, but it can not be abstract. Sized requires the type to be known at compile time.
Sized is a marker trait that requires a constant size at compile time.
Most types have a fixed size that is known at compile time and implement the trait Sized. A type with a size that is known only at run-time is called a dynamically sized type (DST) or, informally, an unsized type.
The special syntax ?Sized can be used to remove this bound if it’s not appropriate.
The dyn keyword is used for dynamic dispatch. It provides runtime polymorphism.
Being object safe means the value is concrete. Self is not object safe because there is no way to get the information from the code to build a vtable to wire the dispatch.
The important point is that the object is dynamically dispatched, but type is not abstract. It is concrete but erased. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.dyn.html
We have two sets of information which conflicts each other. For dyn, type is not known at compile time, but it can not be abstract. Size requires the type to be known at compile time.
